# Calculate Horizontal Pixel Shift for Super Resolution

Tags: image-processing, superresolution

I have a sample that is moving at a constant rate which is known.  Since I know the distance traveled I can equate that with the number of pixels for the pixels shift.  The only way I can think to do this is to do a camera calibration but I am working on a small scale and was wondering if there is another way to calculate the pixel shift for each image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have an item in an image that is moving at a known constant speed in real units, but you want to know how to convert that speed into pixels per second (or whatever time unit)? If that's the case, then you can calculate it based on measurements - have the item move from one side of the image to the other, and count the number of pixels it has moved and in how long, and you have your rate.

Comment: It seems so obvious now.  Thanks for your response.